# invoke web service How to add parameters

Tags: powershell

[postman demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n97y.gif)

I used the following code to call the web service, but it didn't work. I have used postman to test successfully. Here is the demo.

Comment: $body = @{
 "access_token"="24.b305c9822131e65eda05e29c157dd719.2592000.1559103982.282335-16139329",
 "image"="base64",
 "language_type"="CHN_ENG",
 "probability"="true",
 "detect_direction"="true"
} 

$header = @{
 "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
} 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/ocr/v1/general_basic" -Method 'Post' -Body $body -Headers $header

Comment: My code can't be used, need to be modified, thanks in advance

Comment: Don't post code snippets in comments; Please [edit] the question instead and add a [mcve] and format it properly using the  **{}** (_code sample_ icon above the editing area).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$body = @{ 
"access_token" = "24.b305c9822131e65eda05e29c157dd719.2592000.1559103982.282335-16139329";
"image" = "base64"; 
"language_type" = "CHN_ENG";
"probability" = "true";
"detect_direction" = "true"; 
} 
$header = @{ 
"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
} 


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/ocr/v1/general_basic" -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $header  | ConvertTo-Json

$response | Out-File C:\filename.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now have the following tips
The "=" operator is missing after the key in the hash text.
At line: 9 char: 8

Comment: tip:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/ocr/v1/general_basic" -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing
The "Invoke-WebRequest" item cannot be recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or the name of a runnable program. Please check the spelling of the name. If you include the path, make sure the path is correct and try again.
Location Line: 12 characters: 18

Comment: aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/ocr/v1/general_basic Changed to https://aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/ocr/v1/general_basic Still prompted error

Comment: then try Invoke-RestMethod instead of Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: Same tips as before

Comment: It's a bit strange in powershell, I can send it successfully in postman and get the result

Comment: https://www118.zippyshare.com/v/dP6XYjdl/file.html
This is the configuration I used in postman

Comment: give the complete uri with https using Invoke-RestMethod. Updated the answer. check now.

Comment: tip:Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/ocr/v1/general_basic" -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing
The "Invoke-RestMethod" item cannot be recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or the name of a runnable program. Please check the spelling of the name. If you include the path, make sure the path is correct and try again.
Location Line: 12 characters: 18

Comment: aah ! i think your powershell is not updated. Update your powershell version first. At my end this code is working fine.

Comment: My powershell version is 2.0

Comment: How can I save the result of the request as a file?

Comment: thank a lot, I updated to 5.0 and now I get the results, but it's not complete, how to get the results in json format and save them to the desktop?

Comment: Updated the answer. Plz check

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I use the following code to convert the image 1.png into base64 format, but the encoding is displayed in multiple lines, how to display it in one line?
[convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content -path "c:\1.png" -Encoding byte))

Comment: I think it is not related to this question. Please post new question for this.